# How do I parse the following string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to get the Date, FirstName, LastName, and signature values

```
<SignatureInfo Date="6/19/2011 4:13:19 PM" FirstName="Tony" LastName="Jarvis" Signature="mbbIVNZcZmB4EPlrWWDcSGGMKvZ3GVGERxNPnB2AvNRFqOCw4aDHNpeEQ2rB80SzYjpwf7Ur6iH1zjWSeAu2rTEwPfPx/hbIWAtbNKsX6M9AYUecpS1O2JdBfIUw4STkjGqWBsROQv3jr67CVR5ZWqYbGd1NNOQ60G5CV46CiRI=" xmlns="" />
```

Comment: I tried using the NSXMLParser but only knew how to handle XML elements that have a start and end tag. In this case there is no end tag so did not know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy.  Just run it through [**`NSXMLParser`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and look for your namespace elements.

For example, in `didStartElement`, do something like this for each element you want:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict { 
    NSString *firstName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"]];
}
```